# Can Steam be added as an OpenID provider?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Obviously anyone can just put http://steamcommunity.com/openid into the generic OpenID field, but a nice button would be good to make it easier for PC gamers to sign in. Nice buttons are available here: http://steamcommunity.com/dev

(Just so no one thinks I'm trying to be sneaky, I should mention that I work at Valve and am the one that just added the Sign In Through Steam buttons to that page.)

Comment: OT: Please pass my thanks to anyone who was involved in making Portal :)

Comment: Also, thanks for fixing Steam's OpenID, if it was you. ([It didn't use to work until recently :)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55878))

Comment: I see from your picture that you don't have a hat.  I thought that was mandatory at Valve.  Maybe you should ask Robin Walker to share.

Comment: @Jeffrey Robin Walker will not share any hat and probably Joe will be fired for this question. :)

Comment: I second @Juan. Also @Joe, do you think Valve would allow us to use a picture of GlaDOS for the [captcha](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/387/suggest-a-captcha-image/395#395) or the [404](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97/what-should-the-404-image-be-for-the-site/157#157)?

Comment: The buttons are out of style with the remainder of the page I'm afraid...

Answer (score 29):

I think this would be a very good customization for this specific StackExchange, it would give it a nice Gaming Feeling<sup>tm</sup>.

I hope Jeff will consider it.

Answer (score 13):

The last time we checked there were some serious problems with Steam's OpenID support:

[Stack Overflow and Steam Community OpenIDs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55878/stack-overflow-and-steam-community-openids)

edit: OK, I can confirm it works for me as well. This will go out in the next deployment (~8 hours or so from now)

Comment: Huh.  It is working fine for me after the fix a few weeks ago. I'll follow up in the other post and figure out why some people are still having trouble.

Comment: Jeff, I was able to log in successfully here (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/1674/id76561198022869135) /cc @Joe

Answer (score 8):

Good idea. I suppose if the other gaming networks also support OpenID (and I emphasize that I don't know if they do) then it would be good to support them this way too.

Answer (score 2):

Now that [per-site openid provider lists are implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61456/custom-openid-for-sites/67221#67221), I guess it's just a matter of flipping the switch! :)