# Steam profile badge on your Gaming profile badge too?

Tags: feature-request

Now that [Steam is an OpenID provider](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/638/can-steam-be-added-as-an-openid-provider) especially, I think it would be cool if it showed some basic Steam profile info alongside your Gaming SE profile badge (if set on your profile page to allow it). It could maybe just be a link to the Steam site profile. Though quick links to favorite games, or recent game play history, the ability to showcase your Steam achievements, or [inventories](http://teamfortress.com/post.php?id=6202) could be pretty cool.

Comment: Why not simply add a link to your steam profile in the "About Me" section?

Comment: @RavenDreamer: A link is what would work now for power users. But a more explicit Steam integration would be easier for the uninitiated, and would bring the possibility of further integration of Steam data into the badge. I guess the public link could be pulled from the profile (as they do now with twitter, etc.) but then SE would have to scrape the public HTML pages too if SE wanted to get any data from the public profile there. I haven't researched the Steam APIs at all though, so I don't know what they are or are not capable of.

Answer (score 4):

That would be cool. I'd like to extend this by requesting that we also throw in the [Xbox Live gamercard](http://gamercard.xbox.com/DL%20CyberSkull.card) [iframe](http://gamercard.xbox.com/) and the [PSN image card](http://fp.profiles.us.playstation.com/playstation/psn/pid/Lord_CyberSkull.png).